# SQLite database connectivity in Android

Tags: android

I've created an app reg database connectivity.to store and retrieve data.name (first name and last name should be entered) and email id are used in layout. Three buttons are used to show the table, create a table and close at layout.

But while running my app, it's showing "unfortunately the app has been stopped". I'm getting error in logcat.

I have posted my logcat errors and all my code. I don't know where to store the table?

logcat error

```
02-28 22:13:01.430: D/AndroidRuntime(785): Shutting down VM
02-28 22:13:01.430: W/dalvikvm(785): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb4aa8b90)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785): Process: com.example.studentdatabase, PID: 785
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.studentdatabase/com.example.studentdatabase.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at com.example.studentdatabase.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:27)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
02-28 22:13:01.440: E/AndroidRuntime(785):  ... 11 more
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
        android:text="FirstName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
        android:text="LastName" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:text="Email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/lastname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="69dp"
        android:onClick = "Adddata"
        android:text="Create" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="31dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button2"
        android:onClick="Showdata"
        android:text="Show" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/email"
        android:layout_marginRight="24dp"
        android:onClick="close"
        android:text="Close" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.studentdatabase;

import android.R.color;
import android.R.integer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings.System;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String[] Student = null;
    String fname,lname,email;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        db= openOnCreateDatabase("MYDB1 MODE_PRIVATE",null);
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXITS student(fname  VARCHAR,lname VARCHAR,email VARCHAR);");
    }
    private SQLiteDatabase openOnCreateDatabase(String string, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
    private void Adddata(View view)
    {
    EditText editText1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.firstname);
    EditText editText2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.lastname);
    EditText editText3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
    fname = editText1.getText().toString();
    lname = editText2.getText().toString();
    email = editText3.getText().toString();
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Student VALUES('"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+email+"');");
    }

    private void Showdata(View view)
    {
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT from Student",null);
int count = c.getCount();
c.moveToFirst();
TableLayout tableLayout = new TableLayout(getApplicationContext());
tableLayout.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
TableRow tableRow;
TextView textview,textview1,textview2,textview3,textview4,textview5;
tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
textview = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
textview.setText("firstname");
textview.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
textview.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
tableRow.addView(textview);

textview4 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
textview4.setText("lastname");
textview4.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
textview4.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
tableRow.addView(textview4);

textview5 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
textview5.setText("email");
textview5.setTypeface(null,Typeface.BOLD);
textview5.setPadding(20,20,20,20);
tableRow.addView(textview5);

tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
for(int j=0;j<count;j++)
{
    tableRow = new TableRow(getApplicationContext());
    textview1 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textview1.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("fname")));
    textview2 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textview2.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("lname")));
    textview3 = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
    textview3.setText(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("email")));

    textview1.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    textview2.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    textview3.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

    tableRow.addView(textview1);
    tableRow.addView(textview2);
    tableRow.addView(textview3);
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    c.moveToNext();

}
setContentView(tableLayout);
db.close();
    }
public void close(View view)
{
    java.lang.System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: `"unfortunately the app has been stopped` because you are returning `null` from `openOnCreateDatabase` method so `db` is null. see [Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/) for how we use sqlite db in android application

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
db= openOnCreateDatabase("MYDB1 MODE_PRIVATE",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```